# MySQL to Sybase

Tags: mysql, sap-ase

What is the equivalent in Sybase for MySQL:

1. SHOW KEYS FROM
2. DESCRIBE

I've just referred these links, but still in confuse:

[Identifying Sybase tables, fields, keys, constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943420/identifying-sybase-tables-fields-keys-constraints#5038914)

[Discover primary / unique keys in Sybase ASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299550/discover-primary-unique-keys-in-sybase-ase)

I'm guessing that it has something to do with sysobject and syscolumns tables and sp_helpconstraint, but couldn't reach the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SHOW KEYS FROM**

With this code you can get the list of keys from a table.

```
SELECT 
    t.name, 
    CASE k.type 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'PK' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'FK'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Common'
    END,
    c.name
FROM 
    sysobjects t INNER JOIN 
    syscolumns c ON c.id = t.id INNER JOIN
    syskeys k ON k.id = t.id AND c.colid IN (k.key1, k.key2, k.key3, k.key4, k.key5, k.key6, k.key7, k.key8)
WHERE 
    t.type = 'U' AND k.type in (1,2)
```

In order to the `syskeys join` to work properly, you have to use [`sp_primarykey`](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/refman/@Generic__BookTextView/113162;pt=90486) and [`sp_foreignkey`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sprocs/html/sprocs/sprocs113.htm). With this commands you add a row to the `syskeys` table.

You can also use `sp_helpindex 'tablename'`.
Info about constrainst (PRIMARY and FOREIGN included) can also be obtained with `sp_helpconstraint 'tablename'`.

---

**DESCRIBE**

To get the describe info just do `sp_help 'tablename'`.

---

---

**In order to get exactly what you need you can create the selects that you need by editing the stored procedures that I referenced above and creating new ones.** `sp_help`, `sp_helpindex` and `sp_helpconstraint` are located in `syssystemprocs database`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, sorry for not being clear in the first place. What I mean is, the equivalent in term of column output.for MySQL SHOW KEYS FROM: Non_unique, Key_name, Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinality, Sub_part, Packed, Null, Index_type, Comment, Index_comment. for MySQL DESCRIBE: Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra. I am aware of the different between MySQL and Sybase. Anyway, I'll try play around with your code.